# How to use JavaScript to hide a text area

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, textarea

When I  Click on the button a textarea appear allowing the user to type  the message. After they type a message I want textarea to hide.

Can any one help me how to hide the textarea after entering the message?

This my Javascipt code:

```
        <script>
        function showDiv1() {
        document.getElementById('welcomeDiv1').style.display = "block";
                            }
        </script>
```

This my html code:

```
       <div> <span style="display: inline-block;text-align: center; margin:-73px 0px -10px 61px; "><a href ="#"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/reject_5.jpg" width="60" height="60" style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px"  value="Show Div" onclick="showDiv()"/></a><br />Decline</span></div>
       <textarea id="welcomeDiv"  style=" display:none; border:1px solid #666666; height:70px; margin:16px 0 0 8px " class="answer_list" title="Message to Employer" onFocus="this.value=''" > Message to Employer </textarea>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try like this

```
<script>
    function showDiv1() {
        var my_disply = document.getElementById('welcomeDiv1').style.display;
        if(my_disply == "block")
              document.getElementById('welcomeDiv1').style.display = "none";
        else
              document.getElementById('welcomeDiv1').style.display = "block";
     }
</script>
```

It is the simple way of toggling the div using only one function,Ofcourse in JQuery there is only one thing you can do is **'toggle'** the div

Comment: from what the OP has said he wants his Textarea hidden once it's value has changed not when the button is clicked again. I also prefer to use `.style.display != "none"` to show it incase the display property is not set `== ""`.

Comment: He asked that "after he complete the message" So we can assume that he will click it....

Answer (score 1):

Replace `visibility:hidden` with `display: none` :

```
<textarea name="txtReason" id="txtReason" style="display: none;" class="textboxmulti">
</textarea>
```

and then show it by setting it to block:

```
this.form['txtReason'].style.display = 'block';
```

Additionally, you may want to look at jQuery which makes these kind of things extremely easy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('welcomeDiv1').style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Answer (score 0):

run this function on the `onchange` event of the textarea

```
function hideMe(){
   document.getElementById('welcomeDiv1').style.display = "none";
}
```

This completely removes the textarea so that it is hidden and also takes up no space on the page. If you want to hide it but for the space the textarea takes up to remain use `.style.visibility = 'hidden'` instead

Comment: what is the difference between ..style.display ="none" and ..style.visibility = "hidden". If we use display:none, would the textarea content be submitted when the form postback occurs?

Comment: @asim-ishaq Your right with form posts `display="none"` will not post. In this instance using `visibility = "hidden"` is beneficial and the css `position` property can be set to `absolute` to achieve the same visual effect

Answer (score 0):

What about setting the display to "none" after the user changed the input of the textarea.
You may have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/PnfLS/

```
document.getElementById("textbox").addEventListener("change", function(){
document.getElementById("textbox").style.display = "none";
});
```